# Not allowed to load local resource use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php

Hello everyone I was to trying to set up a variable that store my main directory to save time. I know the problem is something to do with file:// is there anyway round this like changing the file:// into http://?

```
$Root_Path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Website";
```

Comment: what code generates the error?

Comment: When I was reading up on the error it said that I can't use file:// but because I'm on a local server it gives me file:// instead of http:// thus causing the error.

Comment: what *it* is giving you the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use:

```
$Root_Path = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/Website";
```

Output:

```
http://yourserver.com/website/
```

UPDATE:

If you really want to get the **root**, use only:

```
$Root_Path = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Output:

```
http://yourserver.com/
```

Comment: This is great, but it's unusable in most php functions like `include();`